# Отличия assertSame и assertEquals в JUnit

Tags: java, junit

JUnit: в чем отличие `assertSame(Object, Object)` от `assertEquals(Object, Object)` именно на параметрах типа `Object`?

Answer (score 8):

`assertEquals()` использует метод `equals()`, если он определен. Таким образом, можно использовать свой принцип сравнения объектов. Если он не определен - работает как `assertSame()`.

`assertSame()` просто сравнивает объекты при помощи оператора `==`, то есть проверяет, являются ли параметры ссылками на один и тот же объект.

Отсюда следует, что для параметров типа `Object` разницы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если runtime-типы обоих параметров - `java.lang.Object`, то ничем.